# Java Substring return 0

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I am developing a numerology app.. Where .. three edit-text are there to collect users first name, middle name and last name.. and among these values only first digit of name is taken and all these values are append using String builder.. and a calculated result is displayed.. The application is working fine if the user enters all firstname, middlename and last name and if for some people there will be no middle name so when they do calculation like that the application is crashing .. pls help ..I am giivng the code below..

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void gReport(View V) 
    {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        long sum2 = 0;

        String firstName = et1.getText().toString();
        String middleName = et2.getText().toString();
        String lastName = et3.getText().toString();
        String aChar1 = firstName.substring(0,1);
        String aChar2 = middleName.substring(0,1);
        String aChar3 = lastName.substring(0,1);

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(aChar1);

        sb.append(aChar2);
        sb.append(aChar3);
        String aChar = sb.toString();
        sum2 = getSum(String.valueOf(aChar));


        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(aChar));
        Intent in = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("name2",sum2 + "");
        startActivity(in);


    }




    private long getSum(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long sum2 = 0;
        char[] name2 = new char[text.length()];

               name2 = text.toCharArray();

               for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
               {
                   sum2 += value2( name2[i] );
                }
                 while (sum2>9)            

               {              

                   sum2 = findDigitSum2(sum2);

               }
        return sum2;
    }

    private long findDigitSum2(long n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum2=0;
        while (n != 0) 
        {
         sum2 += n % 10;
         n = n / 10;
        }
        return sum2;
    }

    private long value2(char a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(a)
        {
           case 'A':return 1;    
           case 'B':return 2;
           case 'C':return 3;
           case 'D':return 4;
           case 'E':return 5;
           case 'F':return 6;
           case 'G':return 7;
           case 'H':return 8;
           case 'I':return 9;
           case 'J':return 1;
           case 'K':return 2;
           case 'L':return 3;
           case 'M':return 4;
           case 'N':return 5;
           case 'O':return 6;
           case 'P':return 7;
           case 'Q':return 8;
           case 'R':return 9;
           case 'S':return 1;          
           case 'T':return 2;
           case 'U':return 3;
           case 'V':return 4;
           case 'W':return 5;
           case 'X':return 6;
           case 'Y':return 7;
           case 'Z':return 8;
           default:return 0;

        }
    }
```

FirstActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity_xm);







        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);

        tv2.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name2"));


}
}
```

Comment: stack trace would help.

Comment: *"I am developing a numerology app ..."* - Well there's your mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably crashing because the middle name field is empty to the length is 0, and you are trying to get a char from a non existing index.
You can use isEmpty() to check if the middleName string is empty or have at least 1 char before using the substring method

for example:

```
String aChar2 = ""; 
if (!middleName.isEmpty())
{
   aChar2 = middleName.subString(0,1);
}
```

Comment: can u pls give an example

Comment: String aChar2 = ""; if (!middleName.isEmpty()) { aChar2 = middleName.subString(0,1);)

Comment: String aChar1 = "";
  if (!firstName.isEmpty())
  {
  aChar1 = firstName.substring(0,1);
  }
  else
  {
   
  }

Comment: It is correct, but you don't need the else, because you do nothing in that else, so you can just remove it.

Comment: Please debug a little bit, you know the theory now, you should be able to figure it out. Also "now it is not working" is not a proper way to describe your problem. What is not working? Where you get an error ?

Comment: tth same thing is happening... how we will give an else condition here..I just tried to return 0; but is also not working

Comment: You should really add code solutions to the answer. You had a wrong bracket at the end. @roshanpeter there is no need for an else statement as it is initialised to `""`

Comment: @ DoomsKnight ... So which value will be given.. if there is no Letter in Edittext

Comment: @Doomsknight yes you are right, hard to write code in the comment box. roshanpeter don't just copy the solution, try to understand what is happening in your app, which kind of error message are you getting, maybe the algorithm is not good if the middle name is missing and so one. Don't wait to somebody with complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the following line:

```
String aChar2 = middleName.substring(0,1);
```

If the middleName is empty this will thrown an IndexOutOfBoundsException (see [this link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Either catch this exception or better yet, check if the String is empty before performing the subString.